# docker react+django, Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

I have a docker running with a service on the backend with Django and DRF, and another at the frontend with react
I'm trying to make an API call from my react to my Django server

```
const getRealItems = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/item`).then(
      (response) => {
        console.log("realItems = ", response)
      }
    )
  }
```

this endpoint works normally on a browser or through insomnia and returns a 200 with the data, I have also tried to replace the endpoint on my method to the pokemon API and received a 200 with the data, so the method is fine

the issue is hitting the endpoint on my server

This is my settings.py

```
...

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'restaurant',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:80",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

...
```

and I added this on my viewset.py

```
class MenuItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MenuItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MenuItemSerializer

    #GET
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is my docker-compose in the case is necessary

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  database:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.postgres
    restart: always
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./backup_data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    depends_on:
      - database
  
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 80:80

  do-migration:
    build: ./backend
    depends_on:
      - backend
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        echo "Apply migration"
        python manage.py makemigrations
        python manage.py migrate
        exit 0
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
  
  nginx_backend_server:
    build: ./nginx_backend_server
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
        - backend
```

but I'm stuck with this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/item' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Edit1:

add a few modifications to my settings.py, same error

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8000",
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ("DELETE", "GET", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT")

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
    "x-user-agent",
)
```

Could it be some missing config on my frontend app??

Comment: Try placing `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` at the top of your middleware stack.

Comment: @jub0bs tried that, same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole weekend on this, I figured out the solution in case anybody stumbles on this in the future:

on INSTALLED_APPS, the corsheaders has to be above your app

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://localhost:3000',  # for localhost (REACT Default)
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://localhost:3000',  # for localhost (REACT Default)
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ["origin"]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

A curl request should have the Referrer-policy set

```
curl -I http://localhost:8000

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Mon, 03 Apr 2023 02:22:15 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 69
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept, Cookie, Origin
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
```

and lastly, on my get:
axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/item`)

was being redirected to 'http://localhost:8000/item/', and so I had to append the trailing / to my requests